# How to sum of a subset of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I am simply trying to sum each column on a selected range of rows and add that sum to the end of the dataframe.

I have tried different pandas functions like at, iat, loc, and iloc but I can't seem to subset and then sum the dataframes correctly.

```
   df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                     '2': ["alpha", 2.34, 0, 4.1234],
                     '3': ["bravo", 20.123, 3.123123, 0]},
                     index=['1', '2', '3', '4'])
```

#df.fillna(0)

I used fillna on the large dataframe to replace the NaN values and the only concern that gives me is #
 that it is an integer that is replacing the NaN.

```
df.loc['sum'] = (df.iloc[2:4, 2:3]).sum(axis = 0)
```

Actual

```
       1       2        3
1      A   alpha    bravo
2      B    2.34   20.123
3      C       0  3.12312
4      D  4.1234        0
sum  NaN     NaN  3.12312
```

Expected

```
       1       2        3
1      A   alpha    bravo
2      B    2.34   20.123
3      C       0  3.12312
4      D  4.1234        0
sum  NaN  6.4634‬  23.24612‬
```

I am pretty sure I am either using iloc incorrectly or the sum function needs me to change the dtypes of the whole frame to make them all floats

Comment: `(df.iloc[1:4, 1:3]).sum()
`

Comment: Just wondering, when do you decide to post as answer and when as comment? @WeNYoBen

Comment: @Erfan sometime it is just very simple question and almost 90% prob duplicate , I left a comments or wrong input (no new method involved)

Comment: I see, makes sense @WeNYoBen